# H5Py throwing OSErrors when I try to open a file with 'a'

Tags: h5py

I'm using H5Py to manipulate some large files and am continuously receiving the following error(s):

```
OSError: Unable to open file (file is already open for read-only)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError: Unable to create file (file exists)
```

The code that I have looks like this:

```
def something_h5py(args, data_file, dir_file):
    # skip if the direction file already exists
    if os.path.exists(data_file):
        f = h5py.File(data_file, 'r')
        if (args.y and 'ycoordinates' in f.keys()) or 'xcoordinates' in f.keys():
            f.close()
            print ("%s is already set up" % data_file)
            return

    f = h5py.File(data_file, 'a')
```

Right above the error message the print statement also returns its message to stdout, but that would mean that the file was closed and therefore there shouldn't be an open file somewhere (which I thought was initially the error).

What else could be causing this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a return case that doesn't close the array?  It's a good idea to use `with h5py.File(...)` block to ensure the file is closed properly.

Comment: Likely the file wasn't closed properly after it previously opened. This happens when there is an unanticipated exit in your program that leaves the file in open status. It could be caused by an error/exception, or a return you didn't account for. If you are running in an interactive console, you can try `f.close()` to close the file. The real solution is to use the `with h5py.File() as f:` context manager to handle cleanly in all situations.